# SQL query to find last date before and all dates after a condition using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case

•   Suppliers having PO date before 01 Jan 21 won’t be considered

•   Exception-If all suppliers have PO date before 1 Jan 21, supplier with latest PO date will be considered.

Check the image for reference
[image: 1]

```
SELECT 
    A.IPN, 
    A.[Manufacturer/Supplier], 
    A.[Last PO#], 
    A.[Last PO Date] 
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IPN,[Manufacturer/Supplier]
        ORDER BY
        (CASE 
            WHEN [Last PO Date] >= '01/01/2021' 
            THEN [Last PO Date]
            WHEN [Last PO Date] < '01/01/2021' 
            THEN MAX([Last PO Date])
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        DESC, IPN DESC) AS rn
    FROM dbo.Sheet1$
) A 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: explain what?  An error will be thrown because of max function so a different approach is required. Please add sample date an expected outcome as text.

Comment: 'Exception-If all suppliers have PO date before 1 Jan 21, supplier with latest PO date will be considered.; - is unclear - does this mean if no manufacturer has a po date after 1/1/21

Answer (score 0):

I used a common table expression (CTE) for selecting records when there are no rows after 2021-01-01, ordering by date.

```
WITH DATA_CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        A.IPN, 
        A.[Manufacturer/Supplier],
        A.[PO#],
        A.[PO Date]
    FROM 
        dbo.Sheet1$ A
    WHERE
        A.[PO Date] < '2021-01-01'
        AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT B.IPN
            FROM   dbo.Sheet1$ B
            WHERE  B.[PO Date] >= '2021-01-01'
        )
    ORDER BY A.[PO Date] DESC
)
    SELECT 
        A.IPN, 
        A.[Manufacturer/Supplier], 
        A.[PO#], 
        A.[PO Date] 
    FROM 
        dbo.Sheet1$
    WHERE
        A.[Last PO Date] >= '2021-01-01'
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        A.IPN, 
        A.[Manufacturer/Supplier],
        A.[PO#],
        A.[PO Date]
    FROM 
        DATA_CTE
```